# How I can use the complex validation condition for GET request in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, get, annotations

Suppose I need to validate the @RequestParam parameter in a GET request. Validation is complex and not basic.
For example, I want the date
`@RequestParam (value = "departureDate") @DateTimeFormat (pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") LocalDate departureDate)`
was in the specified range.
How can I implement it?

For a POST request, I can write my own annotation, in it I need to refer to the request class as a parameter, in a GET request I do not have this class, there are only incoming @RequestParam parameters.

I would be grateful for an example of complex validation for GET.

Comment: put a @Valid after DateTimeFormat annotation

Answer (score 0):

On the controller side validate the date and if the date does not lie in specific range then pass error message.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    LocalDate date1 = sdf.parse("30/01/2020");
    LocalDate date2 = sdf.parse("30/01/2021");
   int result = date1.compareTo(departureDate);
   if(result>0){
    //date1 is after departure date 
   }
 similarly, check both condition.
```